# Pageable attribute size value does not take effect

Tags: java, search, pagination, request

I have an endpoint that amongst other attributes it takes a Pageable.

As known, pageable has three attributes(page, size, sort).

While the first two attributes work fine and I can manipulate the returned list of results by changing their values, the sort attribute doesnt take any effect.

This is my query:

```
http://localhost:8080/api/social/msg/?socialRef=general&fromDate=2020-07-29T22:00:00.000Z&toDate=2020-08-10T14:42:13.325Z&page=0&size=1000&sort=createdAt,desc
```

And the endpoint code:

```
public PaginatedCollection<SocialMsg> CustomCollectionListAll(Pageable pageable, Date lastModifiedBefore, Date lastModifiedAfter, String socialRef)
    return socialService.messages().listAll(toPageableVO(pageable), lastModifiedBefore, lastModifiedAfter, socialRef);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that `createdAt` is a field of your class used by Jpa, and that its Type implements Comparable